# Web API - Keeping the connection opened on a long import process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

We have an MVC5 SPA application where one of our Web API controllers needs to process the import of a file. This process is made once per month, and can take up to 5 hours (our client wants this import to be made via Web API).

Our problem is that the connection is lost (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) after one hour, and we need to keep it opened during the entire process.

We think one option is to send partial content from the server, to let the browser know the connection is still active and processing. In MVC Controller, something like this:

```
public class PartialActionResult : ActionResult
{
    private Counter _counter;
    private Action<Counter> _counterIncrease;

    public PartialActionResult(Action<Counter> counterIncrease)
    {
        _counter = new Counter();
        _counterIncrease = counterIncrease;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            while (_counter.Value < 100)
            {
                _counterIncrease(_counter);
                context.HttpContext.Response.Write("processing...");
                if (_counter.Value == 100)
                    context.HttpContext.Response.Write("OK");
                context.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, we can pass a delegate as reference, and from there we can update the information of the import status.

Is there any option for Web API, as this ActionResult only works for MVC Controllers? Other than that, any option to maintain the connection opened? BTW we cannot use signalR, just in case that might work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you cannot use SignalR, then you are doomed to use a long enough timeout, or switch to polling. There is no other way. Note that calling `Thread.Sleep` as you did is clearly a wrong way to go.

Comment: is it the file upload which takes so long, or just the processing of it? If it's just the processing, hand off the job to a separate background thread (perhaps in a Windows Service) and the notify the user in some way when it's done if necessary - e.g. by email, or provide an API endpoint where they can check regularly for the progress of the job.

Comment: SignalR is definitely the way to go for as @LexLi pointed,another less recommended way is to use `webbackgroundworker` from nugget ,let the background thread handle the task and notify web api.Check http://hansamaligamage.github.io/2016/07/21/I-want-to-run-a-time-consuming-long-process-in-a-one-request/ once.

Comment: @ADyson the issue is in the process. The request from the user is to use this approach (we have several imports. All behave the same way. The client don't want to break the consistency of the design, despite this issue)

Comment: @LexLi my mistake on the example (edited). [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/twmbx/2321921670c7e95f6fad164fbdf3170e) with a polling example. Do you know if by asking the promise will maintain the connection opened? Unfortunately we cannot use signalR... the app on production is under a load balancer, and so far the user does not want to install a backplane for signalR.

Comment: @jparaya all the advice you're getting above is suggesting that maintaining the existing pattern is not a good solution, whatever the client desires. You may have to tell them that the existing design is no longer fit for purpose. For an high quality solution you really want to be using a separate service to process long-running tasks. Relying on the API call not to time out is flakey - either the server or the client could cancel it at any time (or the network fails) and leave your job and data in an ambiguous and possibly un-rescueable state.